# Appscript: Pulling a generated unique ID and emailing it after form response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I need my script to send an email with a unique ID generated after submitting Google Forms. On 2 separate scripts I have managed to:

**1)** After form submission, generate a Unique ID,  push it into the confirmation message and store that ID in Google Sheets:

```js
const EMP = {
  HEADER: "EMP_HEADER",
  PREFIX: "EMP",
  LENGTH: 5,
}

class App{
  constructor(){
    this.ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    this.sheet = this.getLinkedSheet()
    if (!this.sheet) {
      throw Error(`There is no linked form in this spreadsheet.`)
    }
    this.form = FormApp.openByUrl(this.sheet.getFormUrl())
    this.message = this.form.getConfirmationMessage()
    this.empRegex = new RegExp(`${EMP.PREFIX}[\\d]{${EMP.LENGTH}}`, 'gi')
  }

  createEmpByNumber(number){
    return EMP.PREFIX + (10 ** EMP.LENGTH  + number).toString().slice(-EMP.LENGTH)
  }

  getLinkedSheet(){
    return this.ss.getSheets().find(sheet => sheet.getFormUrl())
  }


  getEmpFromConfirmationMessage(){
    const message = this.form.getConfirmationMessage()
    const results = message.match(this.empRegex)
    if (!results) throw Error(`No EMP found in the current confirmation message with regex ${this.empRegex}.`)
    return results[0]
  }

  createNextEmp(currentEmp){
    const nextEmpNumber = Number(currentEmp.replace(EMP.PREFIX, "")) + 1
    return this.createEmpByNumber(nextEmpNumber)
  }

  saveCurrentEmp(emp, rowStart){
    const [headers] = this.sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
    let empHeaderIndex = headers.indexOf(EMP.HEADER)
    if (empHeaderIndex === -1) {
      empHeaderIndex = headers.length
      this.sheet.getRange(1, empHeaderIndex + 1).setValue(EMP.HEADER)
    }
    this.sheet.getRange(rowStart, empHeaderIndex + 1).setValue(emp)
  }

  updateConfirmationMessage(nextEmp){
    const message = this.message.replace(this.empRegex, nextEmp)
    this.form.setConfirmationMessage(message)
  }

  run(e){
    const {rowStart} = e.range
    const currentEmp = this.getEmpFromConfirmationMessage()
    this.saveCurrentEmp(currentEmp, rowStart)
    const nextEmp = this.createNextEmp(currentEmp)
    this.updateConfirmationMessage(nextEmp)
  }
}

function _onFormSubmit(e) {
  new App().run(e)
}
```

**2)** After form submission, send an email with the respondent name and UniqueID
**

- (this last bit of the UniqueID is not currently working, when the email is sent, the part where the UniqueID should be shown in the email is blank). Im guessing
  because the UniqueID is generated and stored in the sheets after the
  email has been triggered. This is where I need help :)

**

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var name = e.namedValues["Name"]
 var email = e.namedValues["Email address"]
 var recipient = email
 var subject = "Welcome"
 var alias = GmailApp.getAliases()
 const code = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4).getValue()
 var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('messagebody')
 template.name = name;
 template.code = code;
 var emailToSend = template.evaluate().getContent();
 GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, emailToSend, {from: alias[0], htmlBody: emailToSend})
}
```

This is what the template looks like:

```html
<div dir="ltr">
    <p>Hola <?= name ?>,
        <br>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align:justify">
        <br>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align:justify">Te damos la bienvenida a ABC.
        <br>Revisaremos tus datos y nos pondremos en contacto contigo para coordinar tu entrevista.</p>
    <p>Tu código para referir amigos es:</p>
    <p><b><font color="#0000ff"><?= code ?></font></b>.</p>
    <p style="text-align:justify">No olvides invitar a un amigo a registrarse.
        <br>
    </p>
    <p><span style="font-size:10px"><em><a href="https://example.com/pdf/terms">Aplican términos y condiciones</a></em></span></p>
    <p><span style="font-size:10px"><em>--</em></span></p>
    <p><span style="font-size:10px"><em>Equipo de ABC</em></span>
        <br><span style="font-size:10px"><em>&quot;Reinventamos&quot;</em><br><em><a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@abc.com<br></a></em></span></p>
    <p><span style="font-size:10px"><em><a href="https://example.com/assets/dist/images/Logo-go.png"><img alt="Logo" src="https://example.com/assets/dist/images/Logo-go.png" width="160" height="70" style="text-align: center; float: left; margin-right: 0px;"></a></em></span></p>
    <div><font color="#1155cc"><span style="font-size:10px"><i><br></i></span></font></div>
    <div><font color="#1155cc"><span style="font-size:10px"><i><br></i></span></font>
        <p>
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
```

THANKS

Comment: Describe the problem as written in [mcve]. "Not working" isn't descriptive enough.

Comment: @TheMaster done. thanks

Comment: What does you template look like?

Comment: @Cooper Hi. I have updated the post including the template. THanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
const code = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4).getValue()
```

to this:

```
const code = e.values[3]
```

also I believe these:

```
var name = e.namedValues["Name"]
var email = e.namedValues["Email address"]
```

should be:

```
var name = e.namedValues["Name"][0]
var email = e.namedValues["Email address"][0]
```

Comment: Sorry not working. It crashed the script with message: Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at onFormSubmit(email-form-confirmacion:2:35).
I beleive var name and var email are working fine. The only value that is not picking up on the email is the const code.

Comment: When you submit please collect this information `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))`

Comment: I do not see the method getLinkedSheet() in the documentation

Comment: They can't be working fine e.namedValues points to an array not an element of the array.  I think you're over complicating this entire process.

Comment: I put both scripts together into one and it didn't break this time. But still not returning the Unique Code on the email. This is the info collected:

{"authMode":"FULL","namedValues":{"Name":["ma"],"Timestamp":["28/10/2023 15:40:23"],"Email address":["example@gmail.com"]},"range":{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":57,"rowStart":57},"source":{},"triggerUid":"19539937","values":["28/10/2023 15:40:23","ma","empleagoperu@gmail.com"]}

Comment: I don't see where you have stored anything in `sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4)`.  I thought maybe it was coming from the form but evidently it is not.

Comment: Hi @cooper, it is not coming from the form. It is being generated after the form is submitted as per the first script I wrote in my initial post. Let me know if that makes sense. It generates a Unique ID like EMP00001

Comment: Yeah I think messing with the linked sheet is a bad idea.  I pretty much leave them alone to collect data.  They are running asynchronously so that makes them a little more difficult to mess with.  I think you're making this whole thing way more complex than it has to be.  If I were you I'd rethink and rewrite the whole.